# intellij + gradle + robolectric + espresso

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, robolectric, android-espresso

I am trying to setup a project using frameworks listed above. I'm using this demonstration project [deckard-gradle](https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle/tree/android-gradle-0.9.2) and i cannot sync gradle. It says that org.robolectric.gradle:gradle-android-test-plugin:0.9.4-SNAPSHOT was not found. How do i fix this? Has anyone made this work? here is the build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.2'
        classpath 'org.robolectric.gradle:gradle-android-test-plugin:0.9.4-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-test'

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 18
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
        androidTest {
            setRoot('src/test')
        }
    }
}

androidTest {
    include '**/*Test.class'
    exclude '**/espresso/**/*.class'
}

dependencies {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        }
    }
    // Espresso
    androidTestCompile files('lib/espresso-1.1.jar', 'lib/testrunner-1.1.jar', 'lib/testrunner-runtime-1.1.jar')
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1',
            'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.1.0',
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1',
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1',
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'

    androidTestCompile('junit:junit:4.11') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    androidTestCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3-SNAPSHOT') {
        exclude module: 'classworlds'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
        exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
        exclude module: 'maven-model'
        exclude module: 'maven-plugin-registry'
        exclude module: 'maven-profile'
        exclude module: 'maven-project'
        exclude module: 'maven-settings'
        exclude module: 'nekohtml'
        exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
        exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
        exclude module: 'plexus-utils'
        exclude module: 'wagon-file'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-shared'
        exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'
}

apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    module {
        testOutputDir = file('build/test-classes/debug')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They currently do not publish snapshot versions of gradle-android-test-plugin. See: https://github.com/robolectric/gradle-android-test-plugin/issues/8